# Synchronize RPM repository atomically

Tags: centos, yum, rpm, repository

We have a RPM repository (on a Centos 6 machine) that we need to push to another machine. So far we've been using `rsync -av --delete` to simply push the repo directory over the network. This makes the remote repository unusable during the sync - before `rsync` finishes, `repodata` don't match the present rpm packages and the synchronization of `repodata` is also not atomic.

How can I synchronize two repositories atomically over ssh?

I would like the remote repository to be usable at any time, even during the transfer of data. I know I could achieve this copying the repo to a temporary directory, and then moving/symlinking it, but it feels like there should be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use **reposync** from the yum-utils package. [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/reposync.1.html). I think it still works with `dnf` if your yum got replaced by that.

`reposync` is a python script. We can see it does

```
# Lock if they've not given an explicit cachedir
...
my.doLock()
```

and if we look at `pydoc yum.YumBase` there is

```
doLock(self, lockfile='/var/run/yum.pid')
  Acquire the yum lock.
```

so it seems to lock against other yum accesses, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Looking at the man page: "synchronize yum repositories to a local directory". I guess I would have to run this from the remote (target) machine? I only have ssh access in one direction, i.e. source repo -> target repo (unless I tunnel stuff).

Comment: Also, does reposync ensure the change is atomic? I.e. during synchronization, the updated repo can be used even during synchronization?

Comment: @Mifeet It locks for yum accesses, see my edit, but perhaps you are doing some other accesses.

Answer (score 0):

A close way would be to rsync to another directory name, then do a couple of quick mv's:

```
rsync -avP repo remote-machine:/dir/repo.new
ssh remote-machine "mv /dir/repo /dir/repo.old; mv /dir/repo.new /dir/repo"
```

Then you could remove the old directory when you wish.  The time that the repo would be unavailable/inconsistent would be minimized.